# Magento 2: Override model class

Tags: magento2

I am trying to override magento-sales/Model/Reorder/Reorder.php to my lcoal code pool but i am getting this error

below is my code

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Sales\Reorder\Model\Reorder;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\CustomerCartResolver;
use Magento\Quote\Model\GuestCart\GuestCartResolver;
use Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder as ReorderHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Data\ReorderOutput;
class Reorder extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Reorder
{

    public function __construct(OrderFactory $orderFactory, CustomerCartResolver $customerCartProvider, GuestCartResolver $guestCartResolver, CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository, ReorderHelper $reorderHelper, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Data\ReorderOutput $ReorderOutput)
    {
        parent::__construct($orderFactory, $customerCartProvider, $guestCartResolver, $cartRepository, $reorderHelper, $logger, $productCollectionFactory,$ReorderOutput);
    }

    public function execute(string $orderNumber, string $storeId): Data\ReorderOutput
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('confirmed');
        die('abc');
    }
}
```

Could not check compatibility between `Sales\Reorder\Model\Reorder\Reorder::execute(string $orderNumber, string $storeId): Sales\Reorder\Model\Reorder\Data\ReorderOutput and Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Reorder::execute(string $orderNumber, string $storeId): Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Data\ReorderOutput, because class Sales\Reorder\Model\Reorder\Data\ReorderOutput is not available in /var/www/html/cybermart_prod_us/app/code/Cybermart/Faq/Model/Reorder/Reorder.php on line 24`

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your constructor code with the below code.

```
public function __construct(
    OrderFactory $orderFactory,
    CustomerCartResolver $customerCartProvider,
    GuestCartResolver $guestCartResolver,
    CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository,
    ReorderHelper $reorderHelper,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Data\ReorderOutput $ReorderOutput
) {
    parent::__construct($orderFactory, $customerCartProvider, $guestCartResolver, $cartRepository, $reorderHelper, $logger, $productCollectionFactory, $ReorderOutput);
}
```

You've forgot to add `\` before the namespace `Magento\Sales\Model\Reorder\Data\ReorderOutput`.

Hope it helps!